# localized enum like extension method

Tags: c#, .net

I created an extenstion method on my custom enum type like

```
public static class GetLocEnum
{
    private static string Translate(this MyEnum e, int lang)
    {
        string res = string.Empty;
        if (lang == 1) 
        {
            switch (e)
            {
                case MyEnum.OptionOne:
                    res = "some title";
                    break;
                case MyEnum.OptionTwo:
                    res = "some title 2";
                    break;
                case MyEnum.OptionThree:
                    res = "some title 3";
                    break;
            }
        }
       // more if's ...
       return res;
    }
}
```

Why I'm not able now to use this as extension in `MyEnum.Translate()` ?

Comment: For reference, here is a [good SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380900/enum-localization) about localization and enums. The accepted answer shows a nice, flexible, approach to localizing your individual enum values.

Comment: chage the access modifier to `public`

Comment: You should always show a *complete* example (you don't actually show how you're trying to call it) along with the exact error message you're receiving. If this is in the same project, I'd expect the compiler error message to be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just because it's private! Change it to public if you want to use it elsewhere.