# How to change string based logic, use enums for example

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This code is working for the English language, but when the language is different all the logic will break, how can it be replaced.

```
if (statuscontent.Contains("detained")) // TODO: remove string based logic
{
  streamWriter.WriteLine("released");
  statuscontent = "released";
}
else if (statuscontent.Contains("released"))
{
  streamWriter.WriteLine("detained");
  statuscontent = "detained";
}
```

thanks for the help

Comment: You could search/read up on globalizing & localizing applications, here's a starting point : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/ or here https://www.infoworld.com/article/3037979/how-to-internationalize-your-application-in-net.html

Comment: *"use enums"* - we can't help you with what is provided. See [mcve].

Comment: It is better you use globalization and localization strategy, for this you need create resource files for each language you want to have in your application. Specifically if you are looking for localization with enums have a look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380900/enum-localization. you will see quite good   answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use localized strings, meaning you add strings to resource files for each supported human language, and then set the culture to select the correct one. It looks like this answer is quite good:
[How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)